# How can I determine the best trace width for my pcb?

Tags: pcb, trace

In my project I use 2 external layers in air. How ever in my circuit the maximal current (Imax) in transient mode is about 70A and in steady sate it gets to 12A.

My question is, how can I know for how long this trace will hold high current above 70A?

Because I used this [site](https://www.4pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.html)
and when I entered the current section 70A then I get the width is: 1.84mm.

What will happen if for a short time (in the transient mode) the current reaches 90A?

Will it destroy the traces of the PCB?

[image]

Comment: Show a screen grab of the calculator with all the settings you've used.

Comment: Per your screenshot, your trace has 2 mm thickness (i.e. height). That's almost certainly not correct. A typical PCB would have 0.04 mm copper thickness on the outer layers. You can have them built with heavier copper than that (at higher cost and with degraded trace/space resolution), but not as much as 2 mm.

Comment: PCB-mounted busbars are often used for high currents.

Comment: one millisecond at 70a, then drops to 12a?

Answer (score 0):

On the website you've linked, there's the in depth-description on how it calculates the width. The more information you put in, the more reliable is the calculate.

To avoid any problem I suggest to oversize your max current.

You wrote you've calculated for 70A. If the current exceeds that value it's possible that the trace breaks. Of course, it also depends on the time that the current exceeds that value so, first of all, I would check the max critic current your board must bear and calculate the width with that value.